# Magento Custom Payment Method. Visible from Admin panel, but not showing in Onepage Checkout from Frontend!

Tags: payment, frontend, payment-methods, admin-panel

I'm trying to create a custom payment method according to this [tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/).
Everything looks fine from back-end. But payment method is not visible from front-end. Could any one help me on what exactly I'm missing.

> /app/code/local/Rahul/Mycheckout/Model/standard.php

```
<?php

class Rahul_Mycheckout_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{

    protected $_code = 'mycheckout';
    protected $_formBlockType = 'mymodule/form';
    protected $_isInitializeNeeded      = true;
    protected $_canUseInternal          = false;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = false;

    /**
     * Return Order place redirect url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
    {
        //when you click on place order you will be redirected on this url, if you don't want this action remove this method
        return Mage::getUrl('customcard/standard/redirect', array('_secure' => true));
    }
    public function isAvailable() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

> /app/code/local/Rahul/Mycheckout/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rahul_Mycheckout>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Rahul_Mycheckout>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <mycheckout>
                <class>Rahul_Mycheckout_Model</class>
            </mycheckout>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <mycheckout>
                <class>Rahul_Mycheckout_Helper</class>
            </mycheckout>

        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <mycheckout>
                <class>Rahul_Mycheckout_Block</class>
            </mycheckout>
        </blocks>
    </global>

    <default>
        <payment>
            <mycheckout>
                <model>mycheckout/standard</model>
                <!-- very important thing, here you select the model for your payment 
                    method -->
                <active>1</active>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>CUSTOM CARD</title>
                <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
                <submit_url>https://someurl.com</submit_url>
                <merchant_id>Insert merchant id</merchant_id>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            </mycheckout>
        </payment>
    </default>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mycheckout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Rahul_Mycheckout</module>
                    <frontname>customcard</frontname>
                </args>
            </mycheckout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> /rahul/app/code/local/Rahul/Mycheckout/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <mycheckout translate="label comment" module="paygate">
                    <label>Custom CARD MyCheckOut</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <order_status translate="label">
                            <label>New Order Status</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status
                            </source_model>
                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </order_status>
                        <submit_url>
                            <label>Gateway URL</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>58</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </submit_url>
                        <merchant_id>
                            <label>Merchant ID</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>59</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </merchant_id>
                        <allowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Payment Applicable From</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries
                            </source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </allowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Countries Payment Applicable From</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>70</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country
                            </source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            <depends>
                                <allowspecific>1</allowspecific>
                            </depends>
                        </specificcountry>
                        <sort_order translate="label">
                            <label>Sort Order</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        </sort_order>
                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </fields>
                </mycheckout>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: show us some code

Answer (score 2):

1. Implement method "isAvailable" in your payment class and let it return true;

   `public function isAvailable($quote = NULL)`
2. rename your standard.php to Standard.php
3. If it still don't work, remove $_formBlockType property

Comment: Same issue! Added following code to php file in module:
`public function isAvailable() {
  return true;
 }`